# How to move and resize the browser's window in Microsoft EDGE browser?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

As per the Microsoft release update [EDGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467845(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Window objects associated with frames are no longer affected by
>   moveTo, moveBy, resizeTo, or resizeBy

In this case , How can we move a window to the desired location through JavaScript?

My code which is working across all browsers IE 11, Firefox, Chrome but not with EDGE.

my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="openWin()">Create new window</button>
<button onclick="moveWinTo()">Move new window</button>
<button onclick="moveWinBy()">Move the new window by 75 * 50px</button>

<script>
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=250, height=250");
}

function moveWinTo() {
    myWindow.moveTo(150, 150);
    myWindow.focus();
}

function moveWinBy() {
    myWindow.moveBy(75, 50);
    myWindow.focus();
}
</script>

</body>
```

[[Edge] window.moveTo() doesnt work with EDGE](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/1850904)

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer edited, thanks

Comment: Edge does not fully support the Window object (I have a Windows Insider version installed which does not support it either). The use of a Window object is not part of the ECMAScript standard as far as I am aware, so I doubt Edge will ever support these functions.

Comment: Why would you *want* to move windows around at all? Popups are supposed to die anyway.