# How to start the window maximized in IE Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, maximize

I have a piece of JavaScript code that I have used for years to start IE windows maximized. Unfortunately this code no longer works in IE Edge. Here is the code:

```
top.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
top.moveTo(0, 0);
```

top is the highest window possible. I have had a look around but cant seem to find an alternative to this which works in IE Edge. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think IE blocks it if it is not a single tab.

Comment: The code is for maximizing a course being launched in its own window from a learning management system. So there will never be any other tabs

Comment: So why are you not setting width and height in window.open()? Or is it just firing it in the new window because there is no pop up?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035167/how-to-move-and-resize-the-browsers-window-in-microsoft-edge-browser but no answer there other than not supported.

Comment: The course is launched in a pop up window. Yeah I read it was no longer confirmed and then searched about for a fix but was unable to find one. So thought I would post a question to see if anyone out there knows a fix

Comment: So are you not setting top,left,width,height in the pop up? Or does the browser ignore that too. :)

Comment: First bit sets the pop up window to the available width and height of the screen, We make sure the start bar is still visible so take a bit of height to compensate for this. Then the second part makes sure its at the top left of the screen. IE Edge ignores both